# scanner does not read after space character

Tags: java

I have 2 inputs from user. One is say `greetings` and the other one is `tell me your name`

But when I write after something hello, `ex: Hello mate!!`  Scanner does not read the second input which is `mate` and takes `hello` from first string second one is also same

any advice

Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Choose what would you like to say ?");

        String str1 = "";
        String str2 = "";

        System.out.println("Say any greetings word");
        str1 = input();
        System.out.println("Tell me your name");
        str2 = input();

        if (str2.equalsIgnoreCase("zia")) {
            System.out.println("Hello Mr Zia, What a nice suprise");

        }

        else {
            System.out.println(str1 + " " + str2);
        }

    }

    public static String input() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        return sc.next();
    }
```

Comment: you want nextLine() not next()

Comment: Why do you create a new scanner on each method call? Don't do that. Create one and reuse that. Note that `next()` only reads the next token (delimiter is whitespace). You want `nextLine()` which reads a complete line (delimiter is newline). Please always read through the method documentation before asking questions like this. The documentation explains the method in detail and also gives examples. See the [official documentation of Scanner#next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need `sc.nextLine()` to read the whole input.

Second, you shouldn't create a new scanner every time. Just re-use the scanner like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Say any greetings word");
str1 = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Tell me your name");
str2 = sc.nextLine();
```

And close the scanner if you don't need it any more:

```
sc.close();
```

That way you don't even need the `input()`-method any more.

Comment: Technically, you should almost never call a close() method, and instead let a try-with-resource handle the closing of your resources. Also since the Scanner is built on System.in, which was not opened by the programmer but by the platform, closing it is a questionable responsibility.

Comment: Also why does everyone insist on using nextLine()? The question is very clear that the two parts of the input are on the same line. next() is the correct call.

Comment: @kumesana Look at the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()
"Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner." The token is delimited by a space character.

Comment: and a space is a delimiter unless specified otherwise. The input is Hello mate!! which is "Hello" followed by one delimiter followed by "mate!!". OP is using next() as it is expected

Comment: @kumesana yes, the space is a delimiter. But the problem is exactly that the scanner only reads to this delimiter! I assume OP wants to read the whole input and not just the first word.

Comment: OP wants two things. next() is called twice, and with OP's input, gives two things.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot build more than one Scanner on the same input stream. They will conflict with each other, leading to the inconsistencies you're observing.

With your program as shown every call to the method input() will build a new Scanner on the one unique System.in. That's more than one Scanner on the same input stream. Won't work.

Instead, build one Scanner once and for all, at the very beginning of your program, and use that one unique Scanner every time you need to read input.

Like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Choose what would you like to say ?");

    System.out.println("Say any greetings word");
    String greeting = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Tell me your name");
    String name = scanner.next();

    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("zia")) {
      System.out.println("Hello Mr Zia, What a nice suprise");
    } else {
      System.out.println(greeting + " " + name);
    }
  }
```